# Unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libstdc++'

Tags: opencv, g++, libstdc++

I'm getting a g++ compiler error (compiling OpenCV 3.0 beta) on OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite.

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.0.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14
Configured with: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc5/gcc5/work/gcc-5-20150421/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin14 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc5 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc5 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-5 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-5 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc5/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-isl=/opt/local --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc5 5-20150421_0'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.0.1 20150421 (prerelease) (MacPorts gcc5 5-20150421_0) 

$ cd ~/opencv-3.0.0-beta/samples/cpp

$ g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -stdlib=libstdc++ facedetect.cpp -o facedetect
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libstdc++'

$ cd ~/opencv-3.0.0-beta/build
$ make
[  2%] Built target zlib
[  2%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_stream.cxx.o
c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libstdc++'
make[2]: *** [3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_stream.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/all] Error 2
```

Comment: Use Clang instead: `export CC=clang`.

Comment: $ CC=clang CXX=clang++ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -Wno-dev -DNVCC_FLAGS_EXTRA="-Xcompiler -stdlib=libstdc++; -Xlinker -stdlib=libstdc++" -DOPENCV_EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++" -DOPENCV_EXTRA_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++" ..

Comment: Still not right ...--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /opt/local/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.4)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -stdlib=libstdc++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -stdlib=libstdc++ -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /opt/local/bin/gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -

Answer (score 2):

`-stdlib=libstdc++` is a Clang option, you can't use it with GCC.